# Show Current Git Branch in Xcode 4.2

Tags: git, branch, xcode4.2

This is a simple question that has been bugging me.

In XCode 4.2, is there anyway to display the git branch that is currently being edited?

I know I can see this from the organizer (or do it from the command line), but what I want to see is the branch name up there in lights next to the project and file name in XCode itself - which is the tool I use 99.9% of the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see from "[XCode4 User Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/SCM/SCM.html)", the organizer view remains the only way to quickly see the current branch (as you already knew).

There doesn't seem to be an overlay added to the other views in XCode4, no overlay related to Git.

Comment: Tanks .. I wasn't sure I was going blind or not