# Is there a better way to see which Git branch I am on in the XCode 7 Interface?

Tags: xcode, xcode7-beta5

I'd like to be able to see which Git branch I am currently working on at a glance in the XCode 7 (beta 5) interface without going through the menu system. Is this possible? I want to see the equivalent of running `git branch` from the command line which adds a star next to the current branch.

There are other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143450/show-current-git-branch-in-xcode-4-2) which ask the question for earlier versions of XCode and I'd like to know if anything has changed or if anyone has any cleaver workarounds / solutions.

The only place I can see it is in the Source Control Menu after the project name:

[image]

Its also in the File Inspector in the Source Control Section which I can quickly show/hide using keyboard shortcuts but it would be nicer if I could see it as it is displayed in the Version Editor but without having to switch to the version editor:

[image]

Comment: sounds like a business opportunity for an Xcode plugin or a status bar item!

Answer (score 0):

Hi Codecowboy yes in Xcode 12.3 if you click on the so-called source code navigator (blue) x in the left menu panel header icon bar you should see the name of the project and the associated branch :-)

[image]